# How to display a "NEW"-icon on posts from today

Tags: posts

I have a videosite based on wordpress. I would like it to show a icon on the posts from today. I've tried googling it, but without any succes at all. Any ideas on how to do it or maybe someone has a link to a tutorial on it?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the difference between the post time [(`get_the_time()`)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) and the current time [(`date()`)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) -

for instance, this snippet added to functions.php of your theme would add a new css class to [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) if the post is less than 24hrs old:

```
function post_from_today_class($class) {
//add .new-post-today to post_class() if newer than 24hrs
    global $post;
    if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) $class[] = 'new-post-today';
    return $class;
}

add_filter('post_class','post_from_today_class');
```

you can use the `.new-post-today` class to style something differently in your post div.

the core idea is:

```
if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) { /*do something*/ };
```

edit:
alternatively, direct in a template with its own php tags, use:

```
<?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) : ?>text<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've put the code in functions, but then adding this to the loop:

<?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) { /*do something*/ }; ?>
       test
       <?php endif; ?>

i get the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in public_html/wp-content/themes/WPTube4/index.php on line 82

Comment: Remove the curly braces ("{}") and insert a colon before `/*do something*/`.

Comment: if you want to use the one-liner code in the loop, don't add the larger code to functions.php. the error is from adding extra text and an 'endif' after the code; I'll edit my answer. just see, that @Joseph answered it already.

Comment: As you may have figured out by now, i'm pretty much a noob. Thanks for your patience :-)

The code now looks like this:

       <?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ); ?>
       test
       <?php endif; ?>

And gives me the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in /var/www/titanen.dk/public_html/spillersmart/wp-content/themes/WPTube4/index.php on line 82

Comment: What should "close" the function, if not <?php endif; ?>?